Is there a way to use the applyMapping method of dynamic frames in Scala to select and manipulate fields in an array
In AWS glue I have an array of objects in my data and I want to drop some fields and change the relative nesting and names of other fields on the objects inside the array. I can't find a way to access fields of objects in arrays. The best I could do was use map to go through and drop the fields on each or create an entirely new dynamic frame from scratch but these are both a lot clunkier than applyMapping would be if there was a way to make that work. Is it possible to access the fields of objects in arrays with applyMapping either directly or with some combination of map and then applyMapping?
As an example I have some data that looks like this
{
    "uuid": "910c4561-a67d-44af-bd92-283d2f0a298e",
    "item_id": "910c4561-a67d-44af-bd92-283d2f0a298e",
    "net_price": 104,
    "coupons" : [
      {
        "code": "SDFW44",
        "valid": true,
        "type": "flat",
        "amount": 5,
        "meta": {
          "tf": false,
          "rf" : true,
          "sf": true
        },
        "conditions": [
          {
            "day":["Mon","Tue","Wed"],
            "time_start": "0000",
            "time_end": "1000",
            "bank": true
          },
          {
            "day":["Thur","Fri"],
            "time_start": "0000",
            "time_end": "1200",
            "bank": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}

but I want to be able to use applyMapping to make it look like
{
    "uuid": "910c4561-a67d-44af-bd92-283d2f0a298e",
    "item_code": "910c4561-a67d-44af-bd92-283d2f0a298e",
    "coupons" : [
      {
        "coupon_code": "SDFW44",
        "type": "flat",
        "amount": 5,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "days_valid":["Mon","Tue","Wed"],
            "time_start": "0000",
            "time_end": "1000"
          },
          {
            "days_valid":["Thur","Fri"],
            "time_start": "0000",
            "time_end": "1200"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}



I have managed to do it through multiple steps with relationalize, drop and then applyMapping to get it into the final state but it would be much easier to do it with a single call to applyMapping

can you please provide the schema you have and the schema you want and the language you are using?  Also is the OSS Spark API enough?

@Chris Struggled to get a hold of the actual to and from schema but did manage to get this some what contrived example of a before and after. I've added that the language is Scala. I'm trying to do it with a specific method of dynamic frames in glue which I've now attached a link to. It may well be that what I want to do isn't possible with that method. That said it doesn't say I can't but the docs are a little meh and I couldn't work out how I would try. Hope the added detail helps

It did for standard spark at least :)
